# Are you be able to Wild Shape while paralyzed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, conditions, wild-shape

Would you be able to use Wild Shape while paralyzed in d&d 3.5?

Answer (score 2):

## You cannot use Wild Shape while paralyzed

The [paralyzed](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#paralyzed) condition has the following text (emphasis mine):

> A paralyzed character is frozen in place and **unable to move or act**. A paralyzed character has effective Dexterity and Strength scores of 0 and is helpless , but **can take purely mental actions**. A winged creature flying in the air at the time that it becomes paralyzed cannot flap its wings and falls. A paralyzed swimmer can't swim and may drown . A creature can move through a space occupied by a paralyzed creature — ally or not. Each square occupied by a paralyzed creature, however, counts as 2 squares.

The [Wild Shape](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid#wildShape) supernatural ability from the druid class reads (emphasis mine):

> At 5th level, a druid gains the ability to turn herself into any Small or Medium animal and back again once per day. Her options for new forms include all creatures with the animal type. This ability functions like the alternate form special ability, except as noted here. The effect lasts for 1 hour per druid level, or until she changes back. **Changing form (to animal or back) is a standard action** and doesn't provoke an attack of opportunity . Each time you use wild shape, you regain lost hit points as if you had rested for a night .

While paralyzed, the character is unable to take actions, unless they are purely mental. "Purely mental action" is not a defined term in 3.5e, but it would seem to me that physically changing your body is more than a mental action. Wild Shape requires a standard action to use, so I would rule that **a character is unable to use Wild Shape while paralyzed**.

Comment: A paralyzed character _is_ able to take actions if they are „purely mental“. Spell-like abilities, for instance, _can_ be activated mentally. So the cruxial question would be whether using the SU ability Wild Shape is a „purely mental“ action or not.

Comment: @PeregrinTook Yeah, I've been searching around for the last 45 minutes looking for anything that would classify Wild Shape as "purely mental" or not, but there doesn't seem to be any consensus. If you have something that would classify it as a mental ability that would change my answer, but it seems to me like physically changing your body is a physical ability. I have edited my answer to include this.

Comment: I agree, SU abilities in general probably are not activated mentally. - Also, Wild Shape has quite a lot to do with your body and not so much with your mind :)

Comment: If being paralyzed is sufficient to render wild shape unusable, by extension is being tied up sufficient  to render wild shape unusable? Because I want druids to be able to escape bonds by wild shaping into a snake or a hedgehog. (Also, the *FAQ* addresses some "purely mental" concerns on page 94.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan As far as I know, bound characters are not prevented from taking actions, so what they are able to accomplish while bound would be up to the DM. I think there is a lot more freedom with your body while bound than while paralyzed, I would have no problem with Wild Shape while bound.

Comment: The description of the condition [helpless](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#helpless) says, "A helpless character is paralyzed, *held*, **bound,** sleeping, unconscious, or otherwise completely at an opponent’s mercy. A helpless target is treated as having a Dexterity of 0 (–5 modifier)" (emphasis mine). And [Ability Score Loss](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#ability-score-loss) says, "Dexterity 0 means that the character cannot move at all. He stands motionless, rigid, and helpless." Perhaps the answer could address this directly?

Comment: I respectfully feel that's another (broader) question to answer.  The OP specifically says paralyzed not helpless.  +1 from me.

Comment: @joedragons If I'm not mistaken, this ruling ultimately makes supernatural abilities generally subject to arbitrary DM decrees. That's okay, I guess. I mean, I would be uncomfortable were the DM to rule that a somehow paralyzed dragon can still use its breath weapon, for instance. So all supernatural abilities aren't equal. Still, I'd rather my druid be able to bust out of a block of ice by turning into an elephant than be told that his immobility prevents him from using wild shape! But, yeah, I guess I'm on board with this being useful advice.

Comment: Does the ability travel with the person in a mind switch. I think that angle should address whether wild shape is purely mental or not.

Comment: @nijineko requiring the mind does not make an ability _purely_ mental. A spell with somatic components would travel in a mind switch, but is definitely not purely mental.